# Fminuc Matlab to Optim R conversion- Increasing the optimization power in R

Tags: r, matlab, optimization

I am currently converting a matlab set of models that calculate the log likelihood using the optimizer `fminunc` to R using `optim 'BFGS'`.

I have the initial values, the maximum likelihood values and end parameter results for all the matlab models. Most of the R converted models can find using optim, the same log likelihood and the same end parameter values using the same initial parameters as matlab. However some get stuck at a local optima which can be fixed by putting in the matlab end parameter values as the initial values, and these models then find the matlab maximum likelihood values.

Is there a more powerful optimization for R, that in on par with matlab's or is it just that R is more likely to get stuck at a local optima and therefore intial parameter values become more critical in them achieving the maximum log liklihood that getting stuck at local optim ?

```
res<-optim(par=x,fn=BOTH4classnochange,hessian=TRUE,method='BFGS',control=list(maxit=MaxIter,abstol=TolFun,reltol=TolX))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [CRAN Task View on Optimization](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) listing every related package?  And yes, there are dozens.